# Path Issue - Getting "localhost" instead the IP

Tags: localhost, ip, paths

Okay, currently I'm trying my WP Theme/Plugin development on LAN so that it can be accessed with multiple devices. What I noticed recently is that the way I include the CSS files makes them not to display in other devices but the host, as it gets an absolute path to "localhost", unknown in clients, instead of 192.168.1.X, and I think would happen the same when going online, as the path is get server side.

Now I include it this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" title="<?php _e('Default'); ?>"/>
```

Is there any fix that makes use of the wp template? (I know that using a relative path would fix it, but I think thats not the way to go) Thanks :P

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `WP_CONTENT_DIR` path in `wp-config.php`

Try adding:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', 192.168.X.X . '/blog/wp-content' );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content